# ADDTIME and SEC_TO_TIME to SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration

I try to change my code from MYSQL to SQL Server.

I have some problems with specific functions (ADDTIME and SEC_TO_TIME) in my query.

Here is the end of my query which i have to change :

```
order by j.idjour,j.heure,ADDTIME(j.heure,SEC_TO_TIME(pl.duree)) asc
```

I tried to use `convert` and `DateAdd` but i am a bit disapointed about how to change it without any error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are 'disappointed about how to change it without any error'? What does this mean? Please show your T-SQL code and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for,

```
dateadd(second, pl.duree, j.heure)
```

Assuming that `pl.duree` is an integer value representing seconds and that `j.heure` is a `time` or `datetime` value.